# $_GET is working but not for $_POST for url query

Tags: php, html, post

I have the following button which opens a new tab/window and redirecting to test.php page. I wanted to post the data of $a to test.php
`<input type="button" onclick="window.open('test.php?var=<?php echo $a;?>','_blank');" value="test"/>`

**test.php**

`$b = $_GET['var'];`

`$_GET` in the above case will be able to retrieve the data posted from the url query, however if I change it to `$b = $_POST['var'];` I get undefined index error for var.

I read from other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/6385066) that I should not use GET for submission of sensitive data. So my question is: How can I modify the code such that I can post the data of variable `var` to test.php using `$_POST`?

Comment: did you also change the `method` in the `form`?

Comment: I don't have a form, just a simple button shown in the question.

Comment: That's impossible without using form

Comment: Either you use a form or AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests include parameters in the URL. If you have a page 'foo.com/bar.php' you can pass it GET parameters in the URL, 'foo.com/bar.php?var=myvar'.

You can then retrieve the parameter using `$_GET`:

`$var = $_GET['var'];`

In a POST request, parameters are included in the request body, not in the URL. So if you want to send `var` using POST you need to use AJAX or submit a form with `method="POST"`.

In your case you're using `GET` and trying to get the value from `$_POST`. That's not possible

Comment: Hmm, I guess I understood what you meant. So there is no way that I can pass the data of `var` with just `<input type="button" onclick="window.open('test.php?var=<?php echo $a;?>','_blank');" value="test"/>`(a simple button) alone? The reason why I didn't use <form> is because I could not aligned the button for the form horizontally to the other simple buttons like <input type="button">. It automatically generates a new line which I could not get rid.

Comment: @DunnoHowToCode No you can't :/ Not without a form or AJAX

Answer (score 0):

With $_GET you will pass the variables via the URL.

If you want to use $_POST, you have to use AJAX:

```
<input type="button" class="post" value="test"/>


 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $(".post").on("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "test.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(response){
                              //do action  
                        },
                        error: function(){
                              // do action
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to do like that you should create hidden value and then when you click on your button then submit that form as a post request to **test.php**

Don't forget to add `target="_blank"` to your form for open in new tab

and if you don't want to create `form` in this page you can redirect it to new page and use javascript for submit form in new page for send post request to **test.php**